# YTDL - Make file name video title

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Im setting up a web application for downloading Youtube videos and i require the application to output

I have tried filename=`{info.title}`.mp4');, filename=${info.title}.mp4');

```
app.get('/download', (req,res) => {
var URL = req.query.URL;
var stream = ytdl(URL);
stream.on('info', (info) => {
    console.log(info.title);
    console.log(info.video_id);
res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=`{info.title}`.mp4');
ytdl(URL, {
    format: 'mp4'
    }).pipe(res);
})});
```

Output should be the title  grabbed from stream.on it and when the file is downloading the file name should be the video title 
Current output : `{info.title}`.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in the middle of a string. You need to put the whole string in backticks instead:

```
res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${info.title}.mp4`);
```

But if you're having trouble with that you can always just concatenate strings instead?

```
res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + info.title + '.mp4');
```